# Initialize structs issues on C

Tags: c, struct, initialization

I'm getting this error during compilation:

> "c:\command_line.h(17): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'
>   Note: C++ does not support default-int
>   command_line.h(17): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not  support default-int"

This my code:

#### command_line.h

```
typedef struct symbol
{
    char* sym_type;
    unsigned short address;
}symbol;


typedef struct symbol_map
{
    char** p_arr_keys;
    symbol* p_arr_values;
    int item_count;
    int array_mode;
    int copy_keys;
}symbol_map;

typedef struct params
{
    int data_counter;
    int code_counter;
    int line_counter;
    int command_len;
    int error_counter;
    int warning_counter;
    symbol_map* p_symbol_map; // (This is line 17- from the error msg)
    char* p_last_symbol
}params;
```

#### main.c

```
params config;
config.code_counter = 0;
config.data_counter = 0;
config.line_counter = 0;
config.command_len = 0;
config.command_first_char = EMPTY;
config.error_counter = 0;
config.warning_counter = 0;
config.p_last_symbol = NULL;
config.p_symbol_map = {NULL}; // (This is line 17- from the error msg)
```

Any idea what's wrong with this initialization?

```
 config.p_symbol_map = {NULL};
```

Comment: Your code doesn't match up, there is no `p_last_symbol` in `struct params`. Aside from that, why the `{}` around the NULL? It's just a pointer.

Comment: That is not an initialisation, it is an assignment.

Comment: You are right about missing p_last_symbol, I forget to add it to here. but the error still exist

Comment: Please don't change the question too much after posting it, people's answers become invalid if you change your source code!

Answer (score 1):

A construct you have used `config.p_symbol_map = {NULL}` is a static initialization and is only allowed in a variable declaration. If you want to assign a NULL to `p_symbol_map` you can simply `config.p_symbol_map = NULL`.

A valid case for static initialization applied to a `symbol` structure would be something like this:

```
symbol sym = {
   NULL,
   0x42
};
```

**updated:**

Btw, you are missing a semicolon after `char* p_last_symbol` in a structure definition.

```
typedef struct params
{
    int data_counter;
    int 
    int line_counter;
    int command_len;
    int error_counter;
    int warning_counter;
    symbol_map* p_symbol_map; // (This is line 17- from the error msg)
    char* p_last_symbol  <----- need to add ; here
}params;
```

Answer (score 0):

You cant do it like that.  You have to initialize the config AFAIK.  You can do this since you are assigning a pointer and not a struct.

```
config.p_symbol_map = NULL;
```

Comment: The error is saying the compiler doesn't know what a symbol_map is.  Are you sure you've copied command_line.h right?  The order which you put the struct definitions in does matter.  Also, you are compiling with C++ not C, so the typedef idiom is not needed.  Are you using C or C++?.

Comment: if you are going to use a C++ compiler, try using typedef struct symbol_map { // other stuff here... } symbol_map_t;

Answer (score 0):

You are not initializing a structure, you are initializing a pointer to a structure.

```
struct foo {
  int a;
  int b;
};

struct foo bar = {.a = 0, .b = 1};
```

But if you are declaring a pointer to it, then you don't have a memory block to initialize at first. So you can't use `{}` idiom to initialize a pointer to `struct`;

```
struct foo *bar;
bar = NULL
```

Comment: Is the `.a` struct member speficier syntax valid C++? I thought it was C99 or something.

Comment: its c99 ...Question was about C. So i presumed user has a modern compiler which supports c99.

Comment: The compiler warning seems to indicate C++ despite the question tag.

Answer (score 0):

Something is wrong there, you are assigning to `p_last_symbol` member which you didn't declare in `params`. Also, `p_symbol_map` is a pointer to something, you can either initialize it with `NULL` or make it point to something else (such as memory allocated with `malloc`).

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for `{}` around `NULL`. Just using `NULL` or `nullptr` would do. Further, what is `p_symbol_map`? There is no such thing in your declaration of params. 
Also, in line 17, it should be wrtten as:

`struct symbol_map* p_symbol_map`. This is the reason there is an error on line 17.

Hope this helped.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answers. I've tried to change it to  just NULL and it didn't help. p_symbol_map is a pointer to the struct symbol_map. I don't think that i need to add struct before line 17, because the struct is already identify

Comment: Did you try using the keyword 'struct' though? Try it and let me know if it works.